# Description list with item and body in separate columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, description

I try to achieve the following layout with a description list

```
Item1     Description of the item where wrapping aligns like this. 
          Should also handle itemize environment in the description body
             * itemize1
             * itemize2
             * itemize3  

Item2     Another description. Another description. Another description.
          Another description. Another description. Another description.
```

I have tried different hackish approaches, like `minipage`, `mbox` etc in the description body. Is there any nice and simple solution for this layout, google didn't help at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for formatting and nest everything in a simple `itemize`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[font=\bfseries]
  \item[Item1]
    Description of the item where wrapping aligns like this. 
    Should also handle itemize environment in the description body
    \begin{itemize}
      \item itemize1
      \item itemize2
      \item itemize3
    \end{itemize}

  \item[Item2]
    Another description. Another description. Another description. 
    Another description. Another description. Another description.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}​
```

For bullets in the nested `itemize`, use

```
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
  %...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: +1 but for the outer `itemize` you don't need to hard-code the `Item1`, `Item2` if you use `\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,label*=Item\arabic*]` and then just `\item`

Comment: @cmhughes: Thanks for noticing this. Since the OP mentions the `description` environment, this leads me to believe that they won't of the simple enumerable `Item1`, `Item2`,... form.